# jenkins git maven releases

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

So i have two maven projects that I control.  One depends on another, say webapp depends on jar library.  I'm trying to setup continuous deployment, so I have the webapp depending on the SNAPSHOT version of the jar library.  Now when I check-in code to the jar and push to the git server, the webapp gets nicely built.  I've setup a post-receive hook on the git server to trigger the jar lib build in jenkins.

Now I'd like to have a one-step (button click) process that would do the following:

assume for starters the pom's have the following in them:

```
<artifactId>jarlib</artifactId>
<versionId>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</versionId>
```

and

```
<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<versionId>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</versionId>
...
<dependency>
  <artifactId>jarlib</artifactId>
  <versionId>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</versionId>
...
```

I'd like two artifacts to be released webapp:0.0.1 and jarlib:0.0.1.  I'd like the poms to now look like:

```
<artifactId>jarlib</artifactId>
<versionId>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</versionId>
```

and

```
<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<versionId>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</versionId>
...
<dependency>
  <artifactId>jarlib</artifactId>
  <versionId>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</versionId>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/index.html).  This pretty much does what you need.  Some of the steps are interactive, but I guess this is taken care by the [M2 Release Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) of jenkins.

Comment: this will not work.  you cannot create a release if you have snapshot dependencies.  what i'm looking for is something that will recognized that my snapshot dependencies are ALSO managed inside the same jenkins instance and that they should be released too.  make sense?

Comment: @ftravers.  Your question said you wanted to release `webapp:0.0.1` and `jarlib:0.0.1.` No mention of `SNAPSHOT`. I am not clairvoyant:)